# Finding the location of CDVViewController.m in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode4

This is probably a really stupid question but yeah... Basically I want to fix the iPhone 5 splash screen bug and I have found what is meant to be a fix:

[iPhone 5 splashscreen not displaying correctly - Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450603/iphone-5-splashscreen-not-displaying-correctly-phonegap)

My issue is that within my project I cannot find CDVViewController.m, or CordovaLib. I can find CDVViewController.h. I assume it must be there because the application works. Where exactly is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Cordova 2.0 or 2.1. It is under the CordovaLib sub-project > Classes > Cleaver > CDVViewController.m

If you can't see CordovaLib, you are probably on an older version and should upgrade to the latest version (currently 2.1).

Answer (score 0):

in order to solve this problem, please check your project "Valid Architectures" in your project build settings (remove armv6 if any) and the "Build Active Architecture Only" should be set to "Yes" (at least for debug).

Cyril