# Splash Screen cut off isuue from top and bottom in phonegap+sencha touch for iphone5

Tags: html, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, splash-screen

I am Working with one phonegap+sencha touch application. 
i have set splash screen for application from xcode. 
i have also used different size of splash screens and also given proper name. 
for iphone4, it take proper image for splash screen, but in iphone5 it display proper image with full screen, but after some time it again adjust to iphone4 size splash screen and there is a cut off with white space at top and bottom. 
is there any solution for adjust this splash screen for iphone5.

here are screens how i show splash screen in iphone5 first and after some time.
[image: First it loaded like this] [image: after some time it set like this, white space at top and bottom]

any help will be appreciated. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: finally i solved my issue using this, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450603/iphone-5-splashscreen-not-displaying-correctly-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Me too had this problem in ios7 4inch display. I was using cordova 2.7. Solved this by editing in CDVSplashScreen.m file. There is a function named update **- (void)updateBounds**

```
- (void)updateBounds{
UIImage* img = _imageView.image;
CGRect imgBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);

CGSize screenSize = [self.viewController.view convertRect:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds fromView:nil].size;

// There's a special case when the image is the size of the screen.
if (CGSizeEqualToSize(screenSize, imgBounds.size)) {
    CGRect statusFrame = [self.viewController.view convertRect:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame fromView:nil];
    imgBounds.origin.y -= statusFrame.size.height;
    //added this code for IOS7
    if (CDV_IsIPhone5() && SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        imgBounds.origin.y=0.0f;
    }

} else {
    CGRect viewBounds = self.viewController.view.bounds;
    CGFloat imgAspect = imgBounds.size.width / imgBounds.size.height;
    CGFloat viewAspect = viewBounds.size.width / viewBounds.size.height;
    // This matches the behaviour of the native splash screen.
    CGFloat ratio;
    if (viewAspect > imgAspect) {
        ratio = viewBounds.size.width / imgBounds.size.width;
    } else {
        ratio = viewBounds.size.height / imgBounds.size.height;
    }
    imgBounds.size.height *= ratio;
    imgBounds.size.width *= ratio;
}


_imageView.frame = imgBounds;}
```

Added this code on the top file

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Hope this will help other viewers also. cheers :)